# How to solve Sqlite Exception: reached max size for compiled sql statement cache for database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am calling selectQuery.

```
public Cursor selectQuery ( final String queryString) {

    try {

        return getReadOnlySQLiteDatabase().rawQuery( queryString, null);
    } catch  ( Exception e ) {
        Logs.show(e);
        return null;
    } catch ( Error e ) {
        Logs.show(e);
        return null;
    } finally {


    }

}
```

Call to the function was

```
c   =   LiveApplication.getDatabaseWrapper().selectQuery( "SELECT   url FROM root_resource where resource_name = 'sports' ");
```

When I am doing this I am getting the exception of 
Reached MAX size for compiled-sql statement cache for database. Please change your sql statements to use '?' for bindargs, instead of using actual values

So i modified my code to

```
public Cursor selectQuery ( final String queryString, final String []  whereArgs) {

    try {
        Log.e("123", "Inside select query----"+whereArgs[0]);
        return getReadOnlySQLiteDatabase().rawQuery( queryString, whereArgs);
    } catch  ( Exception e ) {
        Logs.show(e);
        return null;
    } catch ( Error e ) {
        Logs.show(e);
        return null;
    } finally {


    }

}
```

And call became :

```
c   =   LiveApplication.getDatabaseWrapper().selectQuery( "SELECT url FROM root_resource where resource_name =?", new String[]{"sports"});
```

After this I am not getting anything. What is my mistake here?

Comment: your before and after queries are equivalent, they should give you the same result (minus the prepared statement cache problem). What you did is correct. I guess you introduced another error somewhere else or the state / content of your database has changed